# Parsing this JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string, parsing

I am trying to parse the following JSON in Javascript but haven't been successful

```
{  
   "outer":"{'inner':{'key':'value'}}"
}
```

Using JSON.parse on the above JSON gives an invalid syntax error. I have verified that its a valid JSON. what am I missing?

```
var json = '{"outer":"{'inner':{'key':'value'}}"}';
JSON.parse(json);
```

This gives an unexpected identifier at the 'inner' json

Comment: Show us how you're parsing your JSON and what you expect. `JSON.parse("{\"outer\":\"{'inner':{'key':'value'}}\"}");` works although it probably doesn't give the format you were hoping for.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/jibecet/1/edit?js,console — That parses without error when I test it.

Comment: Re to edit: Notice how there's a `'` before `inner`? That means you're closing your string. You need to escape it. `\'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't your JSON (although it has it's own problems).

You've tried to convert it to a JavaScript string by wrapping it with `'` characters but **it already contains `'` characters** so you have to escape them.

```
var json = '{"outer":"{\'inner\':{\'key\':\'value\'}}"}';
```

You'd *probably* be better off just treating it as an object literal:

```
var not_json = {"outer":"{'inner':{'key':'value'}}"};
console.log(not_json);
```

Comment: I'm not even sure he wants the inner JSON to be a string. Probably a mistake.

Comment: Thanks guys thats helpful, I think I need to first replace the single quotes with double quotes and then parse it

Comment: @user_mda You could but there's really no point in writing it as JSON then parsing it. You may as well do what Quentin said and just make it an object.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I am attempting to parse and the 'value' value of the 'key' thats why I want it to be a json and accessible

Comment: @user_mda: *"thats why I want it to be a json"* If you are working in JavaScript, you almost always want objects and arrays, not JSON. E.g. if you want to create and access the data, then use `var data = {outer: {inner: {key: 'value'}}};`. No need to parse anything. You only need to use JSON if you persist data on disk or transfer data between two systems. JSON is *textual* data representation. Another example: If you want an array of numbers, you create just that: `var data = [1,2,3];`. You likely *won't* create a CSV and "parse" that: `var data = '1,2,3'.split(',').map(x => Number(x))`.

Comment: I guess thats where I am confused, in the above case how can I access the 'value' ? Is the answer string parsing?

Comment: @user_mda — In which above case? In Felix's last comment? No parsing needed. Just `data.outer.inner.key`. When you've got it in your original format where it is a string of JSON-like data as the value of the `outer` property? First you write a custom parser because it isn't JSON.

Comment: data.outer.inner gives me undefined. I understand that its not a JSON so my options are either to write a custom parser or convert it into json to be easily accessible using data.outer.inner.key as you said

Comment: @user_mda: *"so my options are either to write a custom parser or convert it into json to be easily accessible using data.outer.inner.key as you said "* You still seem to confuse JSON with a JavaScript object. JSON is *text* / a *string*. JSON has to be parsed into a JavaScript object or array. This is a string literal containing JSON: `'{"foo": 42}'`. This is a JavaScript object literal: `{foo: 42}` (or `{"foo": 42}`). Maybe this helps: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196), and http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html .